# Custom sign-in page for Azure AD B2C doesn't load on Chrome & Firefox

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We customised our Azure AD B2C tenant's Combined Sign-Up/Sign-In Policy to serve up our own login page. This worked across all the major browsers when we tested last week, but it stopped working today for some of our users on Chrome and Firefox.

We are getting this 404 error when some of our users browse to our home page and they get redirected to the login page (our B2C tenant and custom login URL is redacted but all other query parameters are unchanged):

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/redacted.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_sign_up_in/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/error?code=UX004&diags=%7B%22version%22%3A%222.0.0%22%2C%22user-agent%22%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64%3B%20rv%3A54.0)%20Gecko%2F20100101%20Firefox%2F54.0%22%2C%22online%22%3Atrue%2C%22trace%22%3A%5B%22%231%20T005%20(3ms)%22%2C%22%232%20T027%22%2C%22%233%20T021%20(37ms)%22%5D%2C%22code%22%3A%22UX004%22%7D&csrf_token=YzQ0N3F3NXlTVzBVWTFraG96cmlVU3FVbjVNRmZRbHZ6RURIaHdPRExNRTlDRVRNL3hPN00xRXhoOUV0bnE0V3pYc3ZYcEg0YzRhVnp5WE5QYTJZN0E9PTsyMDE3LTA4LTA4VDAwOjU3OjM2Ljc3MjM1MDlaO283Mm9nSFVXb3lIbWtVZy9CeHZVbFE9PTt7Ik9yY2hlc3RyYXRpb25TdGVwIjoxfQ==&tx=eyJUSUQiOiI4MDgwNWE3Ny02OTU2LTRiNGMtYmUyYi05OGZkZGEwYzM4MDkifQ&desc=https%3A%2F%2Fourdomain.redacted.html`

We have tested the following with no success:

- Clearing all our cache and cooking
- Disabled all extensions
- Private browsing/Incognito mode
- Chrome on Android

But Internet Explorer loads the custom sign-in page just fine on their computer!

I have tried searching online for error code UX004 but didn't find anything. Can someone from Microsoft advise what this error code means? Thank you.

Comment: I believe Microsoft has their own forum for asking such questions, don't they?

Comment: can you open developer tools (F12), go to the console and check for any Javascript errors?

Comment: Just got users complaining to me about this today on my site but can't recreate myself... Also custom combined signinup page

Comment: @Rob StackOverflow is one of Microsoft's [recommended support channels](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/forums/) and I believe has good visibility compared to the MSDN Forum

Comment: @Saca no JS errors. It's a 404 error so it hasn't even reached the stage of that being a possibility.

Comment: @BritishDeveloper I tried again this morning and the login input fields are now loading, but without the custom HTML around it. We're beginning to suspect it has to do with using a self-signed certificate. Our production site doesn't have an issue, just our test sites. Of course, the test sites were functioning last week with self-signed SSL cert so am not sure what made it stop working.

Comment: I just find it very interesting that Microsoft does not supply a support forum of their own.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any response from Microsoft, but we tried various fixes. The one that worked for us is to apply a SSL certificate issued by a commonly-trusted issuer on our test domain. I can't confirm that this error message means AAD B2C is complaining of an insecure connection, but it's worth exploring in case it works for anyone else too.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though this may be a CORS issue on your hosted login page. Use (F12) to open up your developer tools, look into the **Console** tab and ensure you have **Preserve log** switched on. Navigate to the website and hopefully the error should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a CORS issue with the storage account. Adding a CORS rule that allowed everything solved the problem.

Go to azure portal (https://portal.azure.com) and open the storage account that contains your custom login page templates. In the right hand navigation find `Settings > Resource sharing (CORS)`

[image]

Add a new rule with the following values

- Allowed origins = *
- Allowed methods = Select all items
- Allowed headers = *
- Exposed headers = *
- Max age = 200

[image]

Hopefully that helps!